# Differential Operator: Solving Simple ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

This will likely be an exceedingly simple question, but the text's use of the operator is confusing me.

To preface, the operator $D$ is defined as:
$$
\frac{d^{n} y}{d x^{n}}=D^{n} y
$$
and can be used as a polynomial operator similarly as,
$$
L=a_{n}(x) D^{n}+a_{n-1}(x) D^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}(x) D+a_{0}(x)
$$
Problem: $$
\begin{array}{l}\text { Let } n=1,2,3, \ldots \text { Discuss how the observations } D^{n} x^{n-1}=0 \\ \text { and } D^{n} x^{n}=n ! \text { can be used to find the general solutions of the } \\ \text { given differential equations. }\end{array}
$$
$$
y^{\prime \prime}=0
$$

Answer:$$
\begin{array}{l}\text { since } D^{2} x=0, x \text { and } 1 \text { are solutions of } y^{\prime \prime}=0 . \text { since they are linearly independent, the } \\ \text { general solution is } y=c_{1} x+c_{2} \text { . }\end{array}
$$

The operator makes sense applied to some $f(x)$. But $D^2x$ doesn't make sense to me. As I understand it any polynomial expression of $D$ is still just an operator. In other words 
$$ D^n = \frac{d^n}{dx^n} $$

If that's correct, how do I get to the provided answer?

Comment: $D^{2}x$ is nothing but $D^{2}f(x)$ when $f(x)=x$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the operator makes sense applied to some $f(x)$, but $D^2x$ does not make sense.

So I infer that you don't realize that $x$ plays the role of $f(x)$, and

$$D^2x=0$$ because $$x''=0.$$

---

Beware that the operator applies to the function on its right.

Comment: In that case, it seems to make sense. $ D^n x^{n-1} = 0 $ and $ D^n x^n = n! $ is simply re-specifying the power-rule.

Comment: @aisync: obviously. What were you missing ?

Comment: It makes perfect sense TY. The problem was hardly a problem and confused me all the more. EDIT: Not missing anything. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

$D$ is just $\dfrac {d}{dx}$:
$$D^2x=D(Dx)=\dfrac {d}{dx}(\dfrac {d}{dx}x)=\dfrac {d}{dx}1=0$$